# Regex to match all URLs except certain URLs

Tags: regex, url

I need to match all valid URLs except:

> http://www.w3.org
>    http://w3.org/foo
>   http://www.tempuri.org/foo

Generally, all URLs except certain domains.

Here is what I have so far:

```
https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?
```

will match URLs that are close enough to my needs (but in no way all valid URLs!) (thanks, http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/!)

```
https?://www\.(?!tempuri|w3)\S*
```

will match all URLs with `www.`, but not in the `tempuri` or `w3` domain.

And I really want

```
https?://([-\w\.]+)(?!tempuri|w3)\S*
```

to work, but afaick, it seems to select all `http://` strings.

Gah, I should just do this in something higher up the Chomsky hierarchy!

Comment: Wow... even by the standards of URL regexen that's a pretty awful one from snipplr there. It'll disallow a huge range of URLs with all sorts of valid punctuation characters before the `?`. In fact it won't even accept the URL of this question. Well anyway... with the negative lookahead, if that's what you want to do, it should go *before* the `([-\w\.]+)` domain name bit you *do* want to match.

Comment: Good point, I didn't really try the snipplr regex out on anything broad before making that "all valid urls" claim. I'll edit that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following regular expression:

```
https?://(?!w3|tempuri)([-\w]*\.)(?!w3|tempuri)\S*
```

only matches the **first four** lines from the following excerpt:

```
https://ok1.url.com
http://ok2.url.com
https://not.ok.tempuri.com
http://not-ok.either.w3.com

http://no1.w3.org
http://no2.w3.org
http://tempuri.bla.com
http://no4.tempuri.bla
http://no3.tempuri.org
http://w3.org/foo
http://www.tempuri.org/foo
```

I know what you're thinking, and the answer is that in order to match the above list and only return the **first two** lines you'd have to use the following regular expression:

```
https?://(?!w3|tempuri)([-\w]*\.)(?!w3|tempuri)([-\w]*\.)(?!w3|tempuri)\S*
```

which, in truth, is nothing more than a slight modification of the first regular expression, where the

```
(?!w3|tempuri)([-\w]*\.)
```

part appears twice in a row.

The reason why your regular expression wasn't working was because when you include . inside the ()* then that means it can not only match **this.** and **this.this.** but also **this.this.th** - in other words, it doesn't necessarily end in a dot, so it will force it to end wherever it has to so that the expression matches. Try it out in a regular expression tester and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Yep, this works as advertised. However, now I realize that the Visual Studio search regex engine doesn't support lookaheads, so I'm off to simplify/sob quietly in a corner.

Comment: For the record, I ended up not being able to use either lookahead or the postfix ? operator. Silly. So I ran `[http|https]\://[^w3|^tempuri|^schemas][org|com|net]\S*` and then `[http|https]\://www\.[^w3|^tempuri|^schemas][org|com|net]\S*`. Boo.

Comment: That's very weird, because the regex I gave you I tested on the .Net regex engine... hmm I'll have to look into that. Maybe it's the .Net 3.5 thing? Do you have the latest?