# Regex to match all https URLs except a certain path

Tags: regex, iis, url-rewriting

I need a regex that will match all https URLs except for a certain path.

e.g.

### Match

https://www.domain.com/blog
https://www.domain.com

### Do Not Match

https://www.domain.com/forms/*

This is what I have so far:

```
<rule name="Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP excluding /forms" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^https://[^/]+(/(?!(forms/|forms$)).*)?$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: Matching url's has been asked hundred of times. But let's forget about searching a duplicate and please tell us what flavor you're using ?

Comment: Hi Hamza, I have tried to find a regex that matches my requirement but couldn't get any.

I am using IIS URL Rewriting module. The rule is to match all except, which is the tricky bit. It would be great if you could help, it would gain me a few hours sleep. This gets me close but not close enough  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277340/regex-to-match-all-urls-except-certain-urls?rq=1

Comment: What should prevent the match exactly, what are the rules for a non-valid URL ?

Comment: I want to catch all https traffic and redirect it to http unless the https url is http://www.domain.com/forms/*

Comment: There seems to be a mistake in your condition, your pattern says "http?" instead of "https". Is that the issue perhaps?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the answers, really appreciate the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way the redirect module works, you should simply use:

```
<rule name="Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP excluding /forms" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^forms/?" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The rule will trigger the redirect to HTTP only if the request was HTTPS and if the path wasn't starting with `forms/` or `forms` (using the `negate="true"` option).
You could also add a condition for the host to match `www.example.com` as following:

```
<rule name="Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP excluding /forms" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^forms/?" negate="true" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.example.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the following pattern: `^https://[^/]+(/(?!form/|form$).*)?$`

**Explanation:**

- `^` : match begin of string
- `https://` : match `https://`
- `[^/]+` : match anything except forward slash one or more times
- `(` : start matching group 1

  - `/` : match `/`
  - `(?!` : negative lookahead

    - `form/` : check if there is no `form/`
    - `|` : or
    - `form$` : check if there is no `form` at the end of the string
  - `)` : end negative lookahead
  - `.*` : match everything zero or more times
- `)` : end matching group 1
- `?` : make the previous token optional
- `$` : match end of line

Comment: @Sniffer Where and how did you test it ?

Comment: I tested it using Expresso and supplied as input the URL that is not supposed to match but Expresso said it is valid.

Comment: @Sniffer Before posting it, I've also tested it. [demo1](http://regex101.com/r/iD3wH9) [demo2](http://regex101.com/r/dR1pU8).

Comment: Well this really weird because i tested the other answers regex and it worked but yours didn't.

Comment: Even though the regex in the question uses "https?", I think OP doesn't want the ? behaviour of matching http also, since he states "match all https URLs" specifically. May want to remove the qn mark there.

Comment: @sundar I intentionally have put it there since he did have it in his expression.

Comment: Sorry my mistake it should only be https

Comment: @Burt Well simple, just remove the `?` :p

Answer (score 5):

Does this give you the behavior you're looking for?

`https?://[^/]+($|/(?!forms)/?.*$)`

After the `www.domain.com` bit, it's looking for either the end of the string, or for a slash and then something that ISN'T `forms`.

Answer (score 3):

I see two issues in the posted pattern `http://[^/]+($|/(?!forms)/?.*$)`

- It misses redirecting URLs such as `https://domain.com/forms_instructions`, since the pattern fails to match those also.
- I believe you have http and https reversed between the pattern and the URL. The pattern should have `https` and the URL `http`.

Perhaps this will work as you intend:

```
 <rule name="Redirect from HTTPS to HTTP excluding /forms" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^https://[^/]+(/(?!(forms/|forms$)).*)?$" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Edit: I've moved the pattern to the  tag itself since matching everything with .* and then using an additional condition seems unnecessary. I've also changed the redirection URL to use the part of the input URL captured by the brackets in the match.

Comment: Thanks sundar, it still doesn't seem to work, I think it is pretty close just not sure why it won't pick up the root of my domain (https://www.domain.com) and redirect it to the http equivalent

Comment: @Burt Do you mean it worked for all pages other than the root domain.com? If so I'd be actually surprised, since the {R:0} in the previous redirection URL should have messed things up if I understand it correctly. I've updated the post with a few changes, please try this version.