# except a certain Url on Regex

Tags: regex

I want to have a exception match to regular expression;

match all other urls except this:

> http://img.youtube.com/vi/????????????/

I tried this format but dosn't work

```
Regex(@"\b\({0,1}(?<url>(www\.|http://www\.|https://|ftp://|http://|(?!http://img\.youtube.com|http://img)[^ ,""\s<)]*)\b"
```

for exception:

```
(?!http://img\.youtube.com|http://img)
```

Comment: Are you sure it's worth complicating your regex for this versus just excluding such URLs whilst processing the matches?

Comment: hehe I'm little confuse of regex pattern and this is my first time to do it, I think my research is not enough :)

Comment: @user3106450, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2277340/205936)

Comment: thanks for the link; this one is working @"http?://(?!img|http://img)([-\w]*\.)(?!img|http://img)\S*"  but my problem now is url. no url shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need...

```
if(!url.startsWith("http://img.youtube.com/vi/"))
{
...
}
```