# How do I include all endings for a url except for a specific ending with Javascript regexs?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a regex to capture all endings in:

```
hello://a.b.c/d/
```

that is, `hello://a.b.c/d/.*`

except for "Main_Page" ending, that is:

```
hello://a.b.c/d/Main_Page
```

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277340/regex-to-match-all-urls-except-certain-urls) answer but when I try my string, the dots between a and b seem to get in the way, so that something like:

```
hello://a.b.c/d/(?!Main_Page)([-\w]*\.)(?!Main_Page)([-\w]*\.)(?!Main_Page)\S*
```

does not work. So as an example, I would like to match to the first 2 lines and not the third below:

> hello://a.b.c/d/Running
>
> hello://a.b.c/d/Maine
>
> <strike>hello://a.b.c/d/Main_Page</strike>

Comment: Are you sure you need a single regex for this? Its much easier if you can use two regexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine:

```
/hello:\/\/a\.b\.c\/d\/(?!Main_Page).*/g
```

[**Online Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dC3zJ4/1)